# Positioning div using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-events

I have 6 different images and 6 different popups as shown below:

[image: six fox sigma]

Now, with JavaScript, I want to do the following:<br>
On click of any of the image:

1. Get the cursor position of the clicked image.
2. Through JavaScript, place the absolute positioned div popup at the top/center of the image (as shown in fig)

This should work in fluid layouts (left/top/bottom/right attributes in %, no px) and also as the browser is resized.

Below is the HTML code:

```
<div><img src="images/book1.gif" /></div>
<div class="resPadDtp">
    <ul class="resDtp2 lightblktxt txtSmall">
        <li class="resDtpPad"><span>Some text 1</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div><img src="images/book2.gif" /></div>
<div class="resPadDtp">
    <ul class="resDtp2 lightblktxt txtSmall">
        <li class="resDtpPad"><span>Some text 2</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried with the CSS...But in my case, I want it with JS..

Comment: A "clicked image" doesn't have a "cursor position". You can get the cursor position, or the image's position, but they're not the same thing. Which do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to take a few educated guesses as to what you want and give you some skeletal JS. Since you provided not even basic HTML, you'll have to adopt it to your specific situation.

```
$popup = $('div#popup');    // change 'div#popup' selector to your absolutely positioned div
$('img').click(function() { // change 'img' selector to be more specific
  var imgpos = $(this).offset();  // object with left and top properties
  var imgwid = $(this).width();
  var popupwid = $popup.width();
  var popuphgt = $popup.height();
  var popupleft = imgpos.top - popuphgt;
  var popuptop = imgpos.left + imgwid/2 - popupwid/2;
  $popup.css({left: popupleft, top: popuptop}).show();
}
```

Comment: That would work - but you're going to need to know what image (list?) you're clicking so you can load the list of images. The Markup the guy is using should have some way of determining that.